# How do I print a single line after a loop in awk?

Tags: xml, loops, csv, awk

I have an awk script that prints header information, then loops through a csv file to create an xml output.  I want to print a single line after the loop completes, but the following script puts the  tag after each row rather than at the end of the file only.  What do I have wrong?

```
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR==1 {
{print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" > "output.xml" }
{print "<Batch>" > "output.xml" }
{print "  <ASWFileVersion>" > "output.xml" }
{print "    <Application>Batch Maintenance</Application>" > "output.xml" }
{print "    <FileFormat>BATCH_XML_01</FileFormat>" > "output.xml" }
{print "    <Release> </Release>" > "output.xml" }
{print "  </ASWFileVersion>" > "output.xml" }
{print "  <BatchHeader>" > "output.xml" }
{print "    <BatchId>965</BatchId>" > "output.xml" }
{print "    <UserBatchId>965</UserBatchId>" > "output.xml" }
{print "    <BatchType>O</BatchType>" > "output.xml" }
{print "    <Description>Brdata Customer Import</Description>" > "output.xml" }
{print "    <CreatedOn>2014-12-05T12:35:30.3930000-05:00</CreatedOn>" > "output.xml" }
{print "    <TargetData>BatchCustomer</TargetData>" > "output.xml" }
{print "    <SaleLevel>0</SaleLevel>" > "output.xml" }
{print "    <Status> </Status>" > "output.xml" }
{print "    <ErrorMessage> </ErrorMessage>" > "output.xml" }
{print "  </BatchHeader>" > "output.xml" }
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        tags[i] = $i
    }
    next
}
{
    print "<BatchCustomer>" > "output.xml"
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "    <%s>%s</%s>\n", tags[i], $i, tags[i] > "output.xml"
    }
    print "</BatchCustomer>" > "output.xml"
}
{print "</Batch>" > "output.xml" }
```

I use the following command:

```
sudo gawk -f tst.awk customers.csv
```

to run the file.  The input file is customers.csv and the file has headers which become the tags.  The script generates a file called output.csv.  I need the  tag to be at the bottom of the file only, not at the end of each segment that is produced from a row.  Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: The braces inside the `NR==1` block around each `print` statement are not doing anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean

```
END {print "</Batch>" > "output.xml" }
```

The rest of the code is also pretty bad, and why are you redirecting every write instead of simply redirecting the entire output?

Comment: I am very new to coding, all my experience is in SQL, so I don't know best practices yet.
That worked, thank you.  
How would you recommend I redirect the output, like this?
    sudo gawk -f tst.awk customers.csv > output.xml

Comment: Yes. That is shorter, more flexible and more efficient.